# Parser Error in VS 2012

Tags: asp.net, css

I am using following code in my master page.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='layer-styles-css'  
     href='css/layerslider.css?ver=3.4.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

It giving me error while debugging it in MS Visual Studio 2012.

```
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: 'layer-styles-css' is not a valid identifier.
```

Please help me to fix it.

Comment: What is your reason for adding the id attribute?

Comment: Do you have any control with `runat="server"` containing the link?

Answer (score 1):

When a control is marked as `runat="server"`, its `id` and the `id` of and all its contained elements need to follow the same naming convention as a C# property.

I can't see your HTML structure, but if you change your dashes `-` to underscores `_`, it'll most likely fix your problem.